# Elasticsearch Bulk Insert Not Working

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

I'm struggling to bulk insert into Elasticsearch and yet every tutorial / guide says I'm doing it correctly. Note my index doesn't exist at all before I execute this call.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/indexnew3/whatever/_bulk

POST BODY
{ "index" : {}}
{ "make" : "Ford", "model" : "Car 1", "mileage" : 1000, "sale_price" : 3000 }
{ "index" : {}}
{ "make" : "Ford", "model" : "Car 2", "mileage" : 2000, "sale_price" : 5000 }
```

Then a `GET` to `http://localhost:9200/indexnew3/whatever/_search` only shows the `Car 1`

I'm executing this via postman. I can't see anything wrong with this....

Comment: You need to add a new line after the second document, otherwise the last line won't be taken into account

Comment: Goodness! That was all!? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was all, simple isn't it ;-)